# Jython open default system webcam

Tags: python, java, opencv, jython, jython-2.7

I would like to make a tool that opens the system default web cam and returns the paths of the taken/selected images. 
I tried to use the cv2 python library, but I couldn't install it, having reported the following error in console:

```
jython -m pip install cv2
```

> DEPRECATION: A future
> version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. Collecting
> opencv-python   ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname:
> pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT',
> 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName':
> (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'pypi.python.org'))}   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either
> of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org',
> 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)':
> /simple/opencv-python/   ERROR: Certificate did not match expected
> hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022
> GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),),
> 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'),
> ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'pypi.python.org'))}   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either
> of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org',
> 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)':
> /simple/opencv-python/   ERROR: Certificate did not match expected
> hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022
> GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),),
> 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'),
> ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'pypi.python.org'))}   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either
> of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org',
> 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)':
> /simple/opencv-python/   ERROR: Certificate did not match expected
> hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022
> GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),),
> 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'),
> ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'pypi.python.org'))}   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either
> of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org',
> 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)':
> /simple/opencv-python/   ERROR: Certificate did not match expected
> hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022
> GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),),
> 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'),
> ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'pypi.python.org'))}   WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None,
> read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by
> 'SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either
> of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org',
> 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)':
> /simple/opencv-python/   ERROR: Certificate did not match expected
> hostname: pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022
> GMT', 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),),
> 'subjectAltName': (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'),
> ('DNS', 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'pypi.python.org'))}   Could not fetch URL
> https://pypi.org/simple/opencv-python/: There was a problem confirming
> the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
> Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/opencv-python/  (Caused by
> SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of
> 'www.python.org', '*.python.org', 'docs.python.org',
> 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)) - skipping   ERROR:
> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement opencv-python
> (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for
> opencv-python ERROR: Certificate did not match expected hostname:
> pypi.org. Certificate: {'notAfter': 'Nov 23 18:41:10 2022 GMT',
> 'subject': ((('commonName', 'www.python.org'),),), 'subjectAltName':
> (('DNS', 'www.python.org'), ('DNS', '*.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'docs.python.org'), ('DNS', 'downloads.python.org'), ('DNS',
> 'pypi.python.org'))} Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/:
> There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded
> with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname
> 'pypi.org' doesn't match either of 'www.python.org', '*.python.org',
> 'docs.python.org', 'downloads.python.org', 'pypi.python.org'",),)) -
> skipping

I was wondering if the library wasn't too advanced for python version 2.7, and I was wondering if using python instead of java for this task was the best choice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is pretty simple: jython doesn't support newer versions of python. But the whole python world really has moved on to python 3. So more and more libraries just won't work in a jython setup any more. The jython folks still discuss (or maybe stopped, not an expert here) how to go to python 3. Me personally, i absolutely wouldn't look to jython for a NEW feature to implement. Either do it with plain python ... or if you need to script something inside a JVM, then see if JShell is for you.

Comment: But note that such kind of library / tools recommendations are off topic here.

Comment: @GhostCat you're right, I expressed myself badly. I have to do this for work and the project is based on Jython.

Comment: Welcome to the club. We had a jython interface for our product (on the test floor), too. Going to abandon it, because just getting the "raw" jython running on our system turns into a problem, not even talking about 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Final Note: I dot hink that "pip" installs allow you to pick specific versions of a library, and you can always try to get the latest available "python 2" version of some library from somewhere. But of course, that can open a huge can of worms with issues to keep you "busy" for many months to come.